# How to know if firebase database index working?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I added index to firebase database but I don't know how it works and is it working?
I indexed on SearchName which is one level down.

Peoples>$uid>SearchName

```
    {
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",
    "Data": {
       "All": {
        "Peoples": {
          ".indexOn": ["SearchName"]
        },
        "Schools": {
          ".indexOn": ["SearchName"]
        } 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you execute a query on a child property, the Firebase server will try to use the index on that property. If such an index does not exist it will instead return all data to the client (and in that case the SDK order/filter the data) **and** it will log a warning in the client's logcat.

So to detect whether your index works: execute a query against the indexed property and check if there's a warning in logcat.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I am using android studio I executed query but how should I log warning using datasnapshot?

Comment: If there is no index, the Firebase client will automatically log a warning if there's no index. You will see it in your logcat output.

Comment: Sir it not showing despite I not indexed query? what log level and filter should I choose?I chosen warn and no filter, searched  by keywords like firebase,google,index but get no response

Comment: If you're having a problem, please share the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without seeing your minimal Android for the query (including the location you query), there is not much anyone can say beyond explaining how the system behaves (as I did in my answer).

Comment: Sir there is nothing wrong in code so I not know what should I share.I added index on SearchName as I mentioned in question but I am not sure if index working or not because I am getting same kind of response from nodes which are indexed and not indexed.As you told I saw logcat of android studio warn filter but there are many many lines every second so I am unable to find warning related to index.  so how actually I can find out if my indexing work